# How do I efficiently implement a singleton listener in a standalone Java application?

Tags: java, singleton, listener

My code:

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventHandler.getInstance().start();
    }
    ...
}

public class EventHandler implements Runnable, SomeEventListener {
    private static final EventHandler INSTANCE = new EventHandler();
    private static final Thread THREAD = new Thread(INSTANCE);
    private static volatile boolean isRunning = false;

    private EventHandler () {}

    private static EventHandler getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void start() {
        isRunning = true;
        THREAD.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    //Listener method that was overriden
    public void onEvent(Event event) {
        //...do stuff
    }

    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            //Does nothing... just keeps the application running. Is this okay?
        }
    }
}
```

There can only be one instance of `EventHandler`. It's working pretty fine but I have some concerns:

1. I find it weird that I have a `run()` method that does nothing but run at an infinite loop. Is this okay?
2. In Windows, when I start up this application. My CPU usage is at 25% but when start on Linux, it goes to 100% CPU usage... why is this?

I really don't have any experience with regards to listeners on a non-web application. I was wondering if you guys can provide some input.

Comment: What do you mean by working fine? Doing nothing?

Comment: @SleimanJneidi What I meant is that my application works the way I want it to. It's just that the CPU usage bothers me and maybe I'm guessing it's caused by the infinite loop...

Comment: So is the body of the loop empty?

Comment: Yes the body is empty. It's just running infinitely because if I don't do that, then my application will shut down immediately once the main method is finished @SleimanJneidi

Comment: All this to prevent the program form halting? Can't you think of a simpler way?

Comment: The easiest alternative I could think of is run this as a J2EE application on a container. That way, I don't have to create this singleton as the web application shuts down if you tell it to. However, I don't think that's the best solution since I don't see any reason why a web app needs to be created for such a simple application @SleimanJneidi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105301/discussion-between-miguel-portugal-and-sleiman-jneidi).

Answer (score 1):

> I find it weird that I have a run() method that does nothing but run at an infinite loop. Is this okay?

No. That is roughly the opposite of okay.

> In Windows, when I start up this application. My CPU usage is at 25% but when start on Linux, it goes to 100% CPU usage... why is this?

Do they have the same number of cores? You're tying up one with your loop.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you would need to give this it's own thread (and therefore why you'd need to implement Runnable and override run() at all).

Now I admit that I don't know what SomeEventListener does, but since you're not calling the onEvent method from your run() method, and that method is all your new thread will do, there should be no reason to create a new thread at all as the onEvent method will (hopefully) be called from a different thread anyway.

Comment: If I don't implement Runnable and run infinitely, when the main method ends, the application exits.

Comment: But it all works how you planned it this way? Because the way I see it, if this is the only thread keeping your application alive, it really shouldn't do a single thing. If this IS your only thread, then you really need to actually handle Events in the run method (catch them and call the onEvent method) because it won't be called from anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how exactly you register your listener and what it does, but maybe you could only create instance of `EventHandler` and then use only its method as some kind of callback:

```
Consumer<Event> con = EventHandler.getInstance()::onEvent;
// When event arrives
con.apply(event);
```

You don't need to start another thread in this approach.

Comment: I don't need to start another thread? If I don't, then the application just exits right away after the main method is done. My app is just a standalone Java app.

Oh and btw, I'm using Java 7